# What goes in the updateTarget function of the createMapping() argument with Maquette?

Tags: javascript, arrays, maquette

I have an array updating every second and I'm going through the advanced section with mapped arrays, and cannot complete the task. I'm stumped at what goes inside the `updateTarget(updatedSource, target) {}` function. The comments and codepen's end there, and nothing is ever shown in the dom. The function is clearly getting called, but I don't know how to update a target with a new source.

Comment: could you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature and typical implementation of the updateTarget parameter is as follows:

```
function updateResult(itemRecord, itemComponent, index) {
  itemComponent.setItemRecord(itemRecord);
}
```

I have created a complete demonstration of createMapping [here](http://codepen.io/johan-gorter/pen/XXZaNP/).